# cannot find module '@babel/preset-env' NPM

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

[image]

Hello I am trying to do some coding and it seems something offed my package.json so bad even on a vscode restart it still won't find the preset-env its looking for.

here's what I've tried.

```
npm uninstall @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

blowing away the entire project and starting fresh and to no avail none of it has worked.

looking at my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "peek-me",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "package.json",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "sanity start",
    "build": "sanity build"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sanity"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@sanity/base": "^2.35.0",
    "@sanity/core": "^2.35.0",
    "@sanity/default-layout": "^2.35.0",
    "@sanity/default-login": "^2.35.0",
    "@sanity/desk-tool": "^2.35.1",
    "@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^2.0.0",
    "@sanity/vision": "^2.35.0",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7",
    "react": "^17.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "webpack-cli": "4.10.0"
  }
}
```

I'm really stumped as to why this is all of a sudden an issue

Comment: is `package.json` really your main entry point

Comment: That was the default setup for the project. When I ran Sanity init. Though I’d like it to be index.js. There’s zero reason it should be defaulting to package.json